# c# 4.0 nullable input parameters to a method

Tags: c#

```
public IQueryable<Profile> FindAllProfiles(string CountryFrom, string CountryLoc)
{
....
}
```

For the above method, is it possible to have nullable input parameters CountryFrom and CountryLoc? When I call this method, I have to pass in the 2 values otherwise I may get exceptions. Any ideas..?

Comment: I'm confused, strings are nullable...

Comment: I think you mean that you need two string inputs and that they should not be null, i.e. how can you force these to be non-null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're writing the method and using C# 4, you can use [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

With it, you can put a default value for the arguments.

If you're just using the function, then you can pass-in String.Empty instead of a null string.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `string` can already be null....

Since you're using a `string`, you'll need to test against `string.IsNullOrEmpty(yourString)` before using the parameter, to verify a value actually exists.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the strings at entry, using `IsNullOrEmpty` is probably the best approach (unless an empty string ("") is valid), you could then return a null or set defaults and process onward or even throw your own exception (and catch it in your calling routine).

I'd be tempted to say that if you have a method call that you know cannot accept null parameters that you check *before* you call the method and handle that within your calling class.

Answer (score 1):

`string` is nullable. Did you mean non-nullable?

Answer (score 1):

`string` is a reference type, and hence already nullable. You can call `FindAllProfiles(null, null)` and the code will at least *compile* fine. Of course, you need to insure the method body appropiately handles null parameters, but that's ancillary.

Alternatively, if you just want to disallow calling the `FindAllProfiles` function with any null parameters at runtime (do you?), just use guard statements at the top of the method as such:

```
if (CountryFrom == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("CountryFrom")
if (CountryTo == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("CountryTo")
```

Side note: function parameter names should be written in *camelCase* according to all style guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks if they can be nullable, yet it seems to imply that they *must not* be null.

Because `string` is a reference type, they are nullable (and must be nullable). There is no way to enforce (at compile time) that they have a non-null value.